# Multiple setTimeout and clearTimeout intervering each other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to accomplish the following. I have multiple forms with a button. When I click on that button, I want it to change color and text for 2 second. When clicked again within that timeframe it resets and the rotation will start over.

So far my codes work as expected, However, when I click on the button of another form within these 2 seconds the rotation stops because `timerId` is cleared by `clearTimeout`.

Look at my example, when you click ‘order1’ and within 2 second you click ‘order2’ then ‘order1’doesn’t change back to its original state. Is there a way to let other forms not interfere with each other?

```js
var timerId, delay = 2000;

$(".product-form").submit(function(e){
 
var button = $(this).find('button[type=submit]'),
  order = button.find("span:eq(0)"),
  added = button.find("span:eq(1)");

  clearTimeout(timerId);
  added.hide();
  order.hide();
  button.addClass("green");
  added.slideDown("slow");

  timerId = setTimeout(function() {
    added.hide();
    order.show();
    button.removeClass("green");
  }, delay); 
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
form {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.hide {
  display: none
}

#button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  background: orange;
}

.green {
  background: green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="product-form" action="#cart" method="post">
  <button id="button" type="submit">
    <span>Order1</span>
    <span class="hide">&#10003; Added</span>
  </button>
</form>
 
<form class="product-form" action="#cart" method="post">
  <button id="button" type="submit">
    <span>Order2</span>
    <span class="hide">&#10003; Added</span>
  </button>
</form>

<form class="product-form" action="#cart" method="post">
  <button id="button" type="submit">
    <span>Order2</span>
    <span class="hide">&#10003; Added</span>
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: If a user clicks the first button, then the second, should the timer for the first button be cancelled? (I'm thinking no, but...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code uses just a single `timerId` for all buttons, so that's why they're stepping on each other. You could store the `timerId` on the button instead, see `***` lines:

```js
var delay = 2000; // *** No timerId here

$(".product-form").submit(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this),                               // ***
      timerId = $this.data("timerId"),               // ***
      button = $this.find('button[type=submit]'),    // ***
      order = button.find("span:eq(0)"),
      added = button.find("span:eq(1)");

  clearTimeout(timerId);
  added.hide();
  order.hide();
  button.addClass("green");
  added.slideDown("slow");

  $this.data("timerId", setTimeout(function() {      // ***
    added.hide();
    order.show();
    button.removeClass("green");
  }, delay));                                        // ***
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
form {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.hide {
  display: none
}

#button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  background: orange;
}

.green {
  background: green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="product-form" action="#cart" method="post">
  <button id="button" type="submit">
    <span>Order1</span>
    <span class="hide">&#10003; Added</span>
  </button>
</form>
 
<form class="product-form" action="#cart" method="post">
  <button id="button" type="submit">
    <span>Order2</span>
    <span class="hide">&#10003; Added</span>
  </button>
</form>

<form class="product-form" action="#cart" method="post">
  <button id="button" type="submit">
    <span>Order2</span>
    <span class="hide">&#10003; Added</span>
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: @AndrewSvietlichnyy - Thanks, fixed!

Comment: Just one question, what is the advantage of using `$this = $(this)` ?

Comment: @PHPhil - `$()` is a function which allocates an object. If you're going to have `$(this)` in multiple places, better to do *one* function call and reuse the resulting object than to repeatedly create and throw away objects. It's not a big deal in this specific code, but it's a habit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make only 3 simple changes:

1. Make `timerId` an array;
2. Remove the `clearTimeout` statement;
3. Since `timerId` is now an array, use `timerId[timerId.length] = setTimeout(function() {`

**Working Example:**

```js
var timerId = [];
var delay = 2000;

$(".product-form").submit(function(e){
 
var button = $(this).find('button[type=submit]'),
  order = button.find("span:eq(0)"),
  added = button.find("span:eq(1)");

  added.hide();
  order.hide();
  button.addClass("green");
  added.slideDown("slow");

  timerId[timerId.length] = setTimeout(function() {
    added.hide();
    order.show();
    button.removeClass("green");
  }, delay); 
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
form {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.hide {
  display: none
}

#button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  background: orange;
}

.green {
  background: green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="product-form" action="#cart" method="post">
  <button id="button" type="submit">
    <span>Order1</span>
    <span class="hide">&#10003; Added</span>
  </button>
</form>
 
<form class="product-form" action="#cart" method="post">
  <button id="button" type="submit">
    <span>Order2</span>
    <span class="hide">&#10003; Added</span>
  </button>
</form>

<form class="product-form" action="#cart" method="post">
  <button id="button" type="submit">
    <span>Order3</span>
    <span class="hide">&#10003; Added</span>
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Two problems: 1. This creates a useless ever-increasing array (its values are never used). 2. Two clicks on the button doesn't cancel the previous timer for that button, as the OP clearly intended.

Comment: Yes, good points. 1) is easily fixed by ensuring that the array never has any more than x elements: `if (array.length > x) {array.shift();}`

Comment: 2) is easily fixed by building a second array parallel to the first. If the newest element of the array is identical to the immediately previous element, then `clearTimeout` may be invoked: `if (buttonNameArray[(array-length - 1)] === buttonNameArray[(array.length - 2)]) {clearTimeout(timerId[(timerId.length - 1)]);}`

Comment: Since there are now two parallel arrays, it may be simpler to replace with a single nested array, in which each element is a two-element array - where one element is the timer and the other element is a string containing the button name.